# Python: How to remove a list of common words from company names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a few thousand common words such as LLC, INC, CO that I need to remove from the end of a few million company names in a pandas dataframe column. The following removes the common words in any position:

```
toexlude = dfwcomwords['ending'].tolist()

data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (toexclude)]))
```

But I only want to remove the words from the end of the name, i.e. "INC INTERNATIONAL LLC" should be "INC INTERNATIONAL". (The above makes it "INTERNATIONAL".) Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Following @ba_ul suggestion below, I receive unbalanced parenthesis error

```
for word in toexclude:
    data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(rf'{word}$', '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-139-c68049bc0f0d>", line 2, in <module>
    data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(rf'{word}$', '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

  File "/anaconda3/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4042, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "<ipython-input-139-c68049bc0f0d>", line 2, in <lambda>
    data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(rf'{word}$', '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

  File "/anaconda3/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 944, in parse
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")

error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data in form of data frame.

Comment: check only for `x.split()[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `word` for two conditions: (1) whether it's in `toexclude` and (2) whether it's the last word in the company name.

```
toexlude = dfwcomwords['ending'].tolist()

def remove_suffix(x):
    x_list = x.split()
    return ' '.join([word for index, word in enumerate(x_list) if not (word in toexclude and index == len(x_list) - 1)])

data['names'] = data['names'].apply(remove_suffix)
```

Edit: For suffixes containing spaces, you can remove them first by using regex and the `str.replace` function of pandas.

```
data['names'] = data['names'].str.replace('S. A. R. L.$', '')

# If you have multiple such unusual suffixes, you can chain all of them together
data['names'] = data['names'].str.replace('S. A. R. L.$', '').str.replace('L L C$', '')
```

`$` in the regex ensures you remove only the occurrences that are at the end of a name.

Edit #2: Based on the new comments, a pure regex solution would probably be best. It's just three lines and should cover all cases.

```
import re

for word in toexclude:
    data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b{}$'.format(re.escape(word)), '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: Except it does not work for company 'PLC PLC' which should result in 'PLC' and also not for 'PLC Rotor PLC' which should return 'PLC Rotor' and not 'Rotor'

Comment: @ ba_ul. That's how I had it ... appreciate some kudos ;)

Comment: Just saw that. One difference though: you're splitting `x` twice unnecessarily. If `x` is large, then there might be a performance penulty.

Comment: I tend to agree to replace the lambda with a def also for clarity...

Comment: I just discovered the 'PLC PLC' issue mentioned by @BrunoVermeulen. Another issue that I didn't raise in my initial question: Suppose that the ending to remove is 'S. A. R. L.'. In that case the [-1] for the last word does not work. Is there another way to code the removal of the terms in the end of the names?

Comment: I would go for preconditioning the data and the toexclude list first and remove the spaces from S. A. R. L. and similar abbreviations and then run the filter. With regex should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I added more code to cover these cases. I used regex as suggested by @BrunoVermeulen

Comment: Thanks @ba_ul. The problem is that I have a very large number of common terms to remove where the common terms are terms like "PVC LTD", "trusted company" etc. So I cannot manually precondition the data to take all different multiple word endings into account. Any ideas on alternative ways to remove these from the end of the words?

Comment: See the new solution at the end.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote. Also, please accept an answer that solves your problem. Otherwise, this question will remain in the queue as unresolved.

Comment: @ba_ul, the help is much appreciated. I get 'error: unbalanced parenthesis' so I cannot make the new suggestion work.

Comment: @ba_ul, the help is much appreciated. For your new suggestion, I get: 'error: unbalanced parenthesis'. To solve it I tried to add re.escape(word) but then get TypeError: decoding to str: 'TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, float found'. `

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: I think f-strings are available in Python 3.6 and later. If yours is older, can you try `r'{}$'.format(word)`?

Comment: I have Python 3.7 so f-strings are not the problem.

Comment: It works in my setup. Does it break due to any specific suffix? Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: I posted the full error traceback in my question above. The following removes single general words but not "S. A. R. L.": `for word in toexclude:
    data['names'] = data['names'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b{}\b$'.format(re.escape(word)), '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
`

Comment: What happens if you use `r'{}$'.format(re.escape(word))`?

Comment: If I use `r'{}$'.format(re.escape(word))` a company name like "Techlia" becomes "Techl" or "Company Medical" becomes "Company Medic" since "ia" and "al" of the abbreviations. With the `\b` I think I only remove the common words from standalone words. But I still cannot directly remove "PVC LTD" from "Rotor PVC LTD". Would `re.sub(r'\b{}$'.format(re.escape(word))` solve it in a safe way?

Comment: This should do I think: `r'\b{}$'.format(re.escape(word))`

Comment: Yep, `re.sub(r'\b{}$'.format(re.escape(word)))` seems to do the trick. A huge thank you for the help. I suppose I shouldn't update your answer myself before I accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change the check as follows:

```
data['names'] = data['names'].apply(
    lambda x: ' '.join([word for i, word in enumerate(x.split()) if not (
        i == len(x.split()) - 1 and word in toexclude)]))
```